# Async/Await forEach Angular 5 HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, foreach, async-await, subscribe

I want to show the spinner when I click on the button, and hide it when I get **all of the data**, but I can't figure out how to use async/await in the given example.

This is the simplified version of my code:

.ts:

```
isLoading: boolean = false;

onLoad() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.http.post(this.Aurl).subscribe(Aresponse => {
        this.Aitems = Aresponse;
        this.Aitems.forEach((Aitem, Aindex) => {
            let Bbody = Aitem.id;
            this.http.post(this.Burl, Bbody).subscribe(Bresponse => {
                let Bitem = Bresponse;
                this.Bitems[Aindex] = Bitem;
            });
        });
    });
    // this.isLoading = false;
}
```

.html:

```
<button (click)="onLoad()">Load</button>

<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="isLoading" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>

<div *ngIf="!isLoading" >  
    <div *ngFor="let Bitem of Bitems">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Either use forkJoin or combineLatest as per your requirement.

Comment: avoid nested subscriptions...

Answer (score 1):

You can use forkJoin

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
onLoad() {
this.isLoading = true;
this.http.post(this.Aurl).subscribe(Aresponse => {
    this.Aitems = Aresponse;
    let observableBatch = [];

    this.Aitems.forEach((Aitem, Aindex) => {
        let Bbody = Aitem.id;
        observableBatch.push(this.http.post(this.Burl, Bbody).subscribe(Bresponse => {
            let Bitem = Bresponse;
            this.Bitems[Aindex] = Bitem;
        }));
    });
    Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch).subscribe(res => this.isLoading = false;);
});
}
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: nesting subscriptions is a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it with forkJoin, the below code is just a rough code to portray the concept.

```
this.isLoading = true;
this.http.post(this.Aurl)
    .do(Aresponse => console.log(Aresponse)
    .mergeMap(Aresponse => Observable.forkJoin(Aresponse.map((item, index) => this.http.post(this.Burl, item.id))))
    .subscribe(resultSet => {
        console.log(resultSet); //handle each value emitted here
        this.loading = false;
        })
```